# How to let the system auto move to the next number by sequence in assembly language

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, irvine32

I want to ask about that how to let the system auto move to the next number
for example: `Num WORD 1,2,3,4,5`

I let system compare the first number which is 1, then I want the system auto move to 2 and 3 and 4 represent. What code should I write?

So if I no need to call +2, +4 those, the code will be long and repeat the same thing.

Here is my completed code:

```
.data 
MyArray WORD 12345, 40000, 1232, 3339, 4497
OddCount DWORD 0
oddNum BYTE "There are ",0
oddNum2 BYTE " odd numbers in the array",0

.code
main proc

P1:
    mov ax, [MyArray]
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    cmp dx,1
    je odd
    jne P2

    odd:
        inc OddCount
        jmp P2

P2:
    mov ax, [MyArray + 2]
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    cmp dx,1
    je odd1
    jne P3

    odd1:
        inc OddCount
        jmp P3

P3:
    mov ax, [MyArray + 4]
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    cmp dx,1
    je odd2
    jne P4

    odd2:
        inc OddCount
        jmp P4

P4:
    mov ax, [MyArray + 6]
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    cmp dx,1
    je odd3
    jne P5

    odd3:
        inc OddCount
        jmp P5

P5:
    mov ax, [MyArray + 8]
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    cmp dx,1
    je odd4
    jne P6

    odd4:
        inc OddCount
        jmp P6

P6:
    mov edx, offset oddNum
    call writestring

    mov eax, OddCount
    call writedec

    mov edx, offset oddNum2
    call writestring

    call crlf
    call crlf
    call crlf

    exit
    main endp

end main
```

The output will be like this:

[output sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTvNP.png)

Answer (score 2):

You want to abstract your code.  Abstraction is done using variables.  The variable you probably want here is a pointer, and, in assembly language we can put such variables in CPU registers — `edx` might be a good choice.  (In your environment, pointers are 32 bits wide.)

Start the pointer at the beginning of the data array (look ahead to see how `edx` is loaded with a pointer to string `oddNum` before the call to `writeString` and do something similar with the array).

Then dereference the pointer to access an element.  To reuse the same code but at the next element, increment the pointer (by 2, using 32-bit arithmetic) so that it refers to the next element, and repeat the same code, starting with the dereference.

You'll need a way to stop the loop, so you can see if the pointer is referring to one element past the last or else use a counter.

---

Division is not necessary for even/odd: you can check for even/odd by doing `test al,1` (followed by jne)

---

In this sequence:

```
    cmp dx,1
    je odd4
    jne P6

odd4:
    inc OddCount
    jmp P6

P6:
```

We don't normally check opposite conditions: if the `je` falls through, we know for sure `jne` will branch, so you could replace the `jne` with an unconditional branch, `j`.  However, you have a branch over a branch, which is unnecessary, as well as a branch to a label that immediately follows (also unnecessary).  Here's an improved sequence:

```
    cmp dx,1
    jne P6

    inc OddCount

P6:
```

To be clear, labels are not seen by the processor, so they don't break up execution.  Only instructions change execution.

Comment: Some people think "variable" means "static storage with a label".  (Perhaps especially MASM users, because MASM actually considers that a variable, with the symbol name actually associated with the storage itself and implying an operand-size, not just the zero-width address before the storage.)  But that's not what you want for looping over an array, just a pointer in a register. It would be good to make that clear.  And maybe also mention that Irvine32 implies 32-bit code, so all this 16-bit stuff is weird.

Comment: Also, like the linked duplicates for the querent's [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332467/how-to-calculate-the-total-of-odd-number-and-print-out-in-assembly-32-bit)  (which I reverted back to its original state since it had been edited to be another copy of this), `test al,1` is even better.  No need to use `test r/m16, imm16` since the bit you care about is at the bottom.  If you did want to stick with same-size operations, use `and ax,1` / `add si, ax` or something instead of branching.